# Alternatives to parameter overrides for AWS SAM deployment with various environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm new to AWS services in general, so this may be a simple where I've gone down a wrong path.

I have an application that consists of some AWS lambda functions, with an API Gateway to access the routes.

I'm trying to make it so I can deploy the application across a `dev`, `staging` and `prod` environment.

In adding a unique domain to the API gateway I end up with a gateway config in my `template.yaml` like so:

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      StageName: "example-stage-name"
      CorsConfiguration:
        AllowOrigins:
          - !Sub "${CorsOrigins}"
    Domain:
      DomainName: !Sub "${APIDomain}"
      CertificateArn: !Sub "${APIDomainARN}"
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      Route53:
        HostedZoneId: !Sub "${APIDomainZoneID}"
```

I'm using `Parameters` for the domain values so they can be different for each environment (i.e. application-dev.example.com, application-staging.example.com, application.example.com).

In my `samconfig.toml` I end up with a long list of parameter overrides to configure this along with the other parameters I have in my app.

```
version = 0.1
[dev]
[dev.deploy]
[dev.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "application-dev"
s3_bucket = "application-dev.example.com"
s3_prefix = "dev-env"
region = "XX-YYYY-Z"
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
parameter_overrides = "MY_ENV=dev APIDomain=application-dev.example.com APIDomainARN=arn:aws:acm:XX-YYYY-Z:123456789123:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123 APIDomainZoneID=ABCDEGHIJ CorsOrigins=https://other.example.com"
```

Is a long list of parameters the expected approach here? Is there a better or more common approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
parameter_overrides = [
  "key1=value1,value2",
  "key2=value3"
]
```

See [this github post](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2253)